# A app isn't opening when i try to open it with OS or csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

import os
os.startfile("C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams.exe")
if i  do this this error is coming

```
'C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams.exe'   
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

if I put r its showing no such file or directory

Comment: Use a raw string (`r"C:\..."`)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the path(`"C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams.exe"`). In Python source code, specific Unicode code points [can be written using the \U escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code), which is followed by eight hex digits giving the code point.

But you have in your path `\U` with eight non hex digits(Which is causing this `SyntaxError`)

```
C:\Users\
```

So one way to solve this by using `r`(raw strings).

```
>>> import os 
>>> os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams.exe")
```

Comment: Thanks i got it resolved with raw strings